# How do I find an AMI for creating a launch configuration in AWS's new console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to select an AMI in the *Create Launch Configuration* screen, but it's impossible to find my needed AMI from the dropdown.

I expect the following menu:

[image]

But AWS currently shows:

[image]

[image]

The dropdown has a lot of AMIs but not what I need.

I can't search for my AMI either - the dropdown isn't finding my existing AMI.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Do you mean `AWS Marketplace`? This tab isn't clickable

Comment: Provide a full window screenshot from the page where you took the 2nd and 3rd attached images please.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I updated screenshot. 3rd image - it is the same dropdown after I start type in the `Search by AMI ID` inptfld

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary which more screenshots I should provide? Anyway, other than a downvote I won't get anything here

Comment: We all have the intention of helping :) I've just posted an answer for your attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AMI field on the *Create Launch Configuration* page does a search by AMI **ID**, not AMI **name**.

Searching for a value like 'Ubuntu' won't work.

Feel free to copy the AMI ID from the first page (e.g. `ami-0069d66985b09d219` is an Amazon Linux 2 AMI in the `eu-west-1` region), paste it in the field & it will find the AMI from your AMIs / AWS marketplace / community etc.

[image]